# MercadoEnvios no muestra opcion "Retiro en sucursal OCA" (Argentina)

Tags: mercadopago

Buenos dias.

Estoy tratando de darle a mis clientes la posibilidad de realizar retiro en sucursal OCA, sin embargo solo me esta dando la posibilidad de 'Acuerdo con el vendedor' y 'Envio a domicilio'.

Mi JSON de preferencias es el siguiente:

```
var preference = {
    "items": [],
    "shipments": {
      "mode": "me2",
      "dimensions": "30x30x30,500",
      "local_pickup": true,
      "zip_code": 1419
    }
  };
```

Cabe aclarar que en mi codigo el array de items no se encuentra vacio sino con toda la data del carrito.

¿ Cual seria el json que debería enviar para que el usuario pueda elegir la opcion de Retiro en Sucursal OCA ?

Gracias,

Juani.

Answer (score 2):

en tu JSON debes eliminar o colocar en **false** la linea de `"local_pickup": true,` ya que esta opción es para que te pongas de acuerdo con el vendedor. Revisa [la documentación aquí](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/use-mercadoenvios/)

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

La disponibilidad de los correos depende de cada país y por lo tanto es necesario revisar si se encuentra disponible o no la opción de retiro en sucursal del correo.

Como bien dijo David en otra respuesta, la opción de `local_pickup` se utiliza para que el comprador retire los productos por tu tienda, y en este caso debe estar en **false**.

Lo que podrías realizar, aunque no siempre se va a poder aplicar con seguridad (y que depende de lo que el comprador elija) es enviar un `default_shipping_method`.

El listado completo de shipping_methods los podes obtener realizando el siguiente request:

`curl -X GET "https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/shipping_methods?shipping_modes=me2&access_token=TU_ACCESS_TOKEN&marketplace=NONE"`

***Nota:*** El marketplace NONE nos asegura que no tengamos las opciones que son sólo para *Mercado Libre*.

Una vez que tenemos el ID que vamos a utilizar en la preferencia debemos enviarlo:

```
var preference = {
    "items": [],
    "shipments": {
        "mode": "me2",
        "dimensions": "30x30x30,500",
        "local_pickup": false,
        "zip_code": 1419,
        "default_shipping_method": 501045
    }
};
```